# Passing strings as array to subroutine and return count of specific char

Tags: perl

I was trying to think in the right way to tackle this: 
-I would to pass say, n elements array as argument to a subroutine. And for each element match two char types *S* and *T* and print for each element, the count of these letters. So far I did this but I am locked and found some infinite loops in my code.

use strict;
use warnings;

```
sub main {

my @array = @_;

while (@array) {
    my $s = ($_ = tr/S//);
    my $t = ($_ = tr/T//);
    print "ST are in total $s + $t\n";
    }
}

my @bunchOfdata = ("QQQRRRRSCCTTTS", "ZZZSTTKQSST", "ZBQLDKSSSS");
main(@bunchOfdata);
```

I would like the output to be:

```
Element 1 Counts of ST = 5
Element 2 Counts of ST = 6
Element 3 Counts of ST = 4
```

Any clue how to solve this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`while (@array)` will be an infinite loop since `@array` never gets smaller. You can't read into the default variable `$_` this way. For this to work, use `for (@array)` which will read the array items into `$_` one at a time until all have been read.

The `tr` transliteration operator is the right tool for your task.

The code needed to get your results could be:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my @data = ("QQQRRRRSCCTTTS", "ZZZSTTKQSST", "ZBQLDKSSSS");

my $i = 1;
    
for (@data) {
    my $count = tr/ST//;
    print "Element $i Counts of ST = $count\n";
    $i++;
}
```

Also, note that `my $count = tr/ST//;` doesn't require the binding of the transliteration operator with `$_`. Perl assumes this when `$_` holds the value to be counted here. Your code tried `my $s = ($_ = tr/S//);` which will give the results but the shorter way I've shown is the preferred way.

(Just noticed you had `=` instead of `=~` in your statement. That is an error. Has to be `$s = ($_ =~ tr/S//);`)

You can combine the 2 sought letters as in my code. Its not necessary to do them separately.

I got the output you want.

```
Element 1 Counts of ST = 5
Element 2 Counts of ST = 6
Element 3 Counts of ST = 4
```

Also, you can't perform math operations in a quoted string like you had.

`print "ST are in total $s + $t\n";`

Instead, you would need to do:

`print "ST are in total ", $s + $t, "\n";`

where the operation is performed outside of the string.

Comment: Thanks @Chris. This explanation not only answers the question but also teaches me a lot of things. As a newbie to Perl, this is the best answer. Thank you.

Comment: `$s = ($_ = tr/S//)` actually worked as it mean `$s = $_ = ($_ =~ tr/S//)`. That said, it needlessly clobbered the contents of `@array`.

Comment: @ikegami but the assignment to $_ breaks the following tr/T//, doesn't it?

Comment: Indeed, it does

Answer (score 0):

Why `tr///`??

```
sub main {
    my @array = @_;

    while (@array) {
        my $s = split(/S/, $_, -1) - 1;
        my $t = split(/T/, $_, -1) - 1;
        print "ST are in total $s + $t\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: `tr///` doesn't use the regex engine, so it's a little more efficient.

Comment: @Dave Cross, Neither does `split /S/` (or if it does, it's in some mode that's much faster than a normal match). Still, `tr/S//` should still be simpler and faster.

Comment: Split, in addition to being not as efficient, also returns one more than the number of S or Ts.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `while` to traverse an array - your array gets no smaller, so the condition is always true and you get an infinite loop. You should use `for` (or `foreach`) instead.

```
for (@array) {
  my $s = tr/S//; # No need for =~ as tr/// works on $_ by default
  my $t = tr/T//;
  print "ST are in total $s + $t\n";
}
```